# When is it safe to watch The Hobbit while reading the book?

Tags: book-adaptation, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

So, I've read that the first movie covers the six first chapters of the book, and it features some parts from LOTR (either book or movie, I'm not sure). But since I'm still reading The Hobbit (book), I wanna know when I can watch the first movie being sure that no spoiler will be given.

If you could answer the same question for the second movie as well, I'd appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by the second book? The Lord of the Rings?

Comment: second movie* 
My bad, sorry ;}

Comment: Just read the book and then watch the movies. The book isn't that long and shouldn't take you more than a week to get through.

Comment: With the kind of liberties the writers took, feel free to jump in whenever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Hobbit movie ends around the end of Chapter 6

Second Hobbit movie ends around the end of Chapter 13

All 3 movies span a little into the LOTR timeline

I would read through Chapter 6, watch the first one, read through the end of Chapter 13, watch the second one, and then read the rest and watch the 3rd one.  There will be a little overlap between book and movie, but not enough to ruin it.